# Oracle/DB2 compare

Tags: database, oracle, db2

I need to find definitions or explanations (DB2 and Oracle) for:

- instance
- database
- connection
- authority
- authorization
- transaction log
- tablespace
- application
- agent
- lock
- lock timeout

Do someone know where can I find this?

Comment: Is this school/homework?

Comment: nope... friends told me, that if I want to learn something about DB I must understand this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very vague; to answer any of it requires understanding most of the rest of it.I can only suggest reading [Chapter 1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#i68236) of [Oracle Database Concepts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm), which covers all of it, and coming back with a more specific question once you've digested all of that.